# Couting a lot of data from over 2000 text files

Tags: sql, database, excel

I have trouble with counting up ports from switch SNMP output. I have over 2000 text files that look like this:

```
 "301SW00134" Model:"WS-C2950G-24-EI"
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
2
2
2
1
1
1
2
2
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1

Sum:


"301SW00140" Model:"WS-C2950G-24-EI"
1
2
...
```

There are about 200 Switches in each txt file. Some of them have 24 ports some 48. Each file stands for diffrent hour.

For example:

1Jun03_00_01 this means that the file was exported on the 1 of June at 3 PM

I want to count all ones in each file for each switch and then draw a chart of UP ports in every our for each switch.

1 means that port is up, 2 down.

I tried with excel, but It didn't go well.

Do you guys know some tool that will do the work ? I though about exporting those files in some data base and then count. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started by processing a single file.

1. Opens FileStream to reduce overhead
2. Reads code line by line
3. If line contains Model it add a new SwitchCounter to an array

   - SwitchCounter: Stores name, model and port count

```js
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverflow\test.txt",  1)
Dim arCounters, intSize
i = 0

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
 s = objFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(s,"Model:") Then
     Set counter = New SwitchCounter
     counter.Init s
     If i = 0 Then 
      ReDim arCounters(0)
     Else
      ReDim Preserve arCounters(i)
     End If
     Set arCounters(i) = counter 
     i = i + 1
    Else
     If IsNumeric(s) Then counter.Add s
    End If
Loop

For Each counter In  arCounters
 WScript.Echo counter.name
Next

Class SwitchCounter
 Public model
 Public name
 Public Count
 '"301SW00134" Model:"WS-C2950G-24-EI"
 Public Sub Init(s)
  s = Replace(s,"Model:", "")
  s = Replace ( s,Chr(34), "")
  
  model = Split(s, " ")(1)
  name = Split(s, " ")(0)
 End Sub
 
 Public Sub Add(n)
  Count = Count + CInt(n)
 End Sub
End Class
```